# Dell Precision 670 not booting

Tags: dell-precision

Our Dell running XP did not boot one day and was making a beep code that I had a hard time finding on the Internet. It was one of the RAM sticks so I replaced it.  Before that I removed the motherboard battery to see if there was a problem with the battery.  Now at start up it tells me that `No Logical Drives Found` and then `BIOS not installed!`.  I have read over a lot of posts here and other places but everyone is talking about installation of the OS.  I just want it to start with what it had.

Comment: Check out the dell website and look for the documentation on the precision 670.

Comment: "BIOS not installed"? This is rather funny. Do you have a SCSI card on that machine?

Comment: The specific motherboard has an Internal SCSI Connection, right beside the SATA ports.